# How to change this SQL query for wordpress?

Tags: php, mysqli, wordpress

I want to create infinite loop for my blog, so I build it with the simple database query format. Now I want to change it to WordPress format but I don't know the right way to do it. Please help me.

```
<?php

$infiloop= $_POST['pcount'];

$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$hostname = "localhost";
$db_name = "dbname";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");


$post_limit= "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' && post_type='post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT ".$infiloop.",10";
$post_list = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$post_limit);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($post_list)) {
   echo $row['post_title']."<br>";
}



if (!$post_list) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbhandle));
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to create an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say, but I want to create infinite loop for wordpress... but the problem is i don't know how to use that LIMIT in wordpress query

Answer (score 0):

I think its very easy to use wp queries instead of using sql. Use the below code to get posts:

```
<ul>
<?php 
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 );    
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>    
</ul>
```

The default "Order by" is by "date".

Comment: I am not good in wordpress query, can yoy tell me how i can use that $infiloop for the limit in this code?

Comment: you really dont need any other queries than the above one. Please refer to wp codex for more. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I tried the above code and the problem is it loops the same 5 posts again and again... Is there any way to define that to show 6 to 10 posts in page?

Comment: set posts_per_page to your number of posts you want. if you want all of them, then set  'posts_per_page' => -1